# Difference between % and the variable it is representing?

Tags: syntax

I have this code. The problem I have is with the % in the Manipulate (after Grid). If I replace % with data, then the values are not evaluated anymore? But how come? Isn't the % refering to data?

```
Clear["Global`*"]

PosH = (1 - pH) (1 - kans);
PosI = pI kans;
NegH = pH (1 - kans);
NegI = (1 - pI) kans;

{{PosH, PosI, PosH + PosI}, {NegH, NegI, NegH + NegI}, {PosH + NegH, 
   PosI + NegI, 1}};
Prepend[%, {"Gezond", "Ziek", ""}];
data = MapThread[Prepend, {%, {"", "Positief", "Negatief", ""}}];

Manipulate[
 AccountingForm[
  Grid[%, Frame -> All], {3, 3}], {kans}, {{kans, 0.0001}, 0, 
  1}, {{pI, 0.99}, 0, 1}, {{pH, 0.99}, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: You need to assign the list to `data` to the result of the two lines of code preceding the existing assignment to `data`. All three of those rows should be assigned to `data` not just the last row.  Then you will be able to replace the `%`s with `data`.

Comment: No, `%` refers to the output value of the output (whether or not the output was suppressed with a `;`).  It does not refer to `data`, but its value.  Apparently `Manipulate` reads in the value of `%` before processing it to create its output. (I didn't know it would do this, but it makes sense to me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot more wrong with your code than the misuse of `%`. The variables you define globally must be brought into the scope to the Manipulate expression. Here is one way to get all the variables properly scoped.

```
DynamicModule[{PosH, PosI, NegH, NegI, data, titles, rowLabels, gridData},
  Manipulate[
    AccountingForm[Grid[gridData, Frame -> All], {3, 3}],
    {{kans, 0.0001}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{pI, 0.99}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{pH, 0.99}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    Initialization :> (
      PosH := (1 - pH) (1 - kans);
      PosI := pI kans;
      NegH := pH (1 - kans);
      NegI := (1 - pI) kans;
      data :=
        {{PosH, PosI, PosH + PosI}, 
         {NegH, NegI, NegH + NegI}, 
         {PosH + NegH, PosI + NegI, 1}}; 
      titles = {"Gezond", "Ziek", ""}; 
      rowLabels = {"", "Positief", "Negatief", ""}; 
      gridData := 
        MapThread[Join[{#1}, #2] &, {rowLabels, Prepend[data, titles]}]),
      TrackedSymbols :> {kans, pI, pH, gridData}]]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: For some reason with this code the values do not refresh if I move one of the sliders (Mathematica 11.0)

Comment: @ImreVégh. There was a comma missing between `Initialization :> ... ` and `TrackedSymbols :> ... ` I have fixed it. Thanks for tell me about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler example:

```
data = {1, x};

Manipulate[%, {x, 0, 1}]
```

My first thought was that this should not work, because I thought `Manipulate` worked by localizing the ***literal*** occurrences of `x` and maps them to the local `DynamicModule` variable created for the control `{x, 0, 1}` when the output is instantiated in the front end. (Most or all of this is explained in the first four tutorials linked in the documentation for [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html), which is fairly heavy reading, but essential for understanding tricky things in `Manipulate` like this issue.)  Since there is no `x` in the body `%` (which is literally `Out[$Line - 1]`) of `Manipulate[%, {x, 0, 1}]`, I thought the control's variable `x` would not be attached to the global symbol `x` in the value of `%`.

However, it turns out that **`Out[]` is handled by `Manipulate` as a special case, and its value is effectively inlined in the body before `Manipulate` constructs the output.**  So `Manipulate[%, {x, 0, 1}]` is effectively equivalent to

```
Manipulate[{1, x}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

and the two behave the same.

On the other hand, in

```
Manipulate[data, {x, 0, 1}]
```

there is no literal `x` and the global `x` in the value of `data` is not connected to the localized `x` of the control.

A possible workaround is

```
Manipulate[data, {x, 0, 1}, LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

Another:

```
Manipulate[Evaluate@data, {x, 0, 1}]
```

But there are better ways.  Basically you need to have the body be a function of the control variables.